# Java, Spacing words in a text precisely in the console

Tags: java

The following instructions have come from Question 4: "Justifying Text" from the [Programming Olympiad 2012: Round 1](http://www.olympiad.org.za/olympiad/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/PO-2012-R1-Q-paper-final-v-2012-07-12.pdf):

> Write a program that will take the provided text and  print it out in
>   a column of a specified width (just like  in a newspaper). Words at
>   the end of a line that  would end beyond the length specified, must be
>   moved to the next line. Spaces must be added  between the words so
>   that each line is exactly the  specified width and the spaces are as
>   evenly  distributed over the line as possible. If only one  word fits
>   in a line, that word must be left-aligned.  The width of a column will
>   always be greater than or  equal to nine. Use the following text: “A
>   great discovery solves a  great problem but there is a grain of
>   discovery in the  solution of any problem”

The approach I am using is to set the amount of digits to use to the width set eg. width 20 = 20 digits. Every digit can either be filled with a letter from the text or a blank space.  This approach does not work very well, since some letters have a wider length than others.

Do you believe my method is permissible?  How could I yield better results with a different algorithm?  How could I improve the code below?

Here is my solution:

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "A great discovery solves a great problem but there is a grain of discovery in the solution of any problem";
        int input = Integer.valueOf(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input: "));

        String[] words = text.split(" ");
        int amDigits = 0;
        ArrayList<String> wordsOfLine = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line = "";

        for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            if(amDigits < input) {
                amDigits += words[i].length() + 1;
                wordsOfLine.add(words[i]);

            }
            else {
            //  System.out.println("Words: " + wordsOfLine);

                int totalWhiteSpace = 0;
                for(int a = 0; a < wordsOfLine.size(); a++) {
                    totalWhiteSpace = input - wordsOfLine.get(a).length();

                }
                int singleWhiteSpace = Math.round((float) totalWhiteSpace/(float) wordsOfLine.size() - 1);
                System.out.println(singleWhiteSpace);

                for(int b = 0; b < wordsOfLine.size(); b++) {
                    line += wordsOfLine.get(b);
                    for(int c = 0; c < singleWhiteSpace; c++) {
                        line += " ";

                    }

                }

                System.out.println(line);

                amDigits = 0;
                line = "";
                wordsOfLine = new ArrayList<String>();
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for advice on a variety of things all at once. The one concrete question you've asked seems to be related to letter width, which is exclusively a question of your console font, not your code.

Answer (score 4):

1. All the code is crammed in the public static void main.  Create at least two methods with intuitive names that explain what they do to make it more readable.  That way I can glance it over and see the main themes of what you are doing.
2. Your for loops check the size of the array on every iteration of the loop.  This is a waste of processor time to re-scan the array every iteration.
3. Instead of calling the class 'main', give it a name of what it does.  like "SetFormattedSpacingWidth" or something that captures the essence of what it does.
4. There is a triple nested for loop.  Triple nested for loops can usually be re-written in a polymorphic way to have only one or at most two for loops.
5. You are using the old manner of for loops, instead of this:

   ```
   for(int b = 0; b < wordsOfLine.size(); b++) {
       line += wordsOfLine.get(b);
       //access words via: wordsOfLine.get(b);
   }
   ```

   Use the new [java foreach loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) to subtract one line and make it more readable.

   ```
   for(String words : wordsOfLine) {
       //access words via: 'words'
   }
   ```
6. Decrementing `i--` INSIDE a for loop that increments i?  That is really confusing.
7. A division by zero exception might happen.  You shouldn't even need to catch those.  They should be impossible to happen.

Here is my attempt at this fun problem:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DoFormattedColumnWidth {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String msg = "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply " +
        "random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin " +
        "literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard " +
        "McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in " +
        "Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, " +
        "consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the " +
        "cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the " +
        "undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and " +
        "1.10.33 of \"de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum\" (The Extremes of Good " +
        "and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on " +
        "the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first " +
        "line of Lorem Ipsum, \"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..\", comes from a " +
        "line in section 1.10.32.";
        ArrayList<String> lines = 
                justifyText(msg, 25);

        for(String line : lines){
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
    public static ArrayList<String> justifyText(String text, int width){

        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

        String[] words = text.split(" ");

        String currentLine = "";
        int currentWord = 0;
        int len = words.length;
        int numberOfWordsThisLine=0;
        while (currentWord < len){      
            if ((currentLine.length() + words[currentWord].length()) <= width || 
                (currentLine.length() + words[currentWord].length()) > width && 
                numberOfWordsThisLine == 0){

                currentLine = currentLine + " " + words[currentWord];
                currentWord++;
                numberOfWordsThisLine++;
                if (currentWord == len)
                    lines.add(currentLine.trim());
            }
            else{
                currentLine = infuseLineWithSpaces(currentLine.trim(), 
                      width - (currentLine.trim().length()));
                lines.add(currentLine.trim());
                currentLine = "";
                numberOfWordsThisLine=0;
            }
        }
        return lines;
    }
    public static String infuseLineWithSpaces(String text, int numSpaces){

        String newText = "";
        if (numSpaces == 0) return text;
        else if (numSpaces == 1) return text + " ";
        else if (numSpaces > 1){
            String[] words = text.split(" ");
            int numberOfWords = words.length;

            int left = (numSpaces + (numberOfWords-1));
            int right = ((words.length-1));

            int numberSpacesToAddEachWord = (int)((double)left / (double)right);

            for(int x = 0; x < numberOfWords; x++){
                if (x == numberOfWords)
                    newText = newText + words[x];
                else
                    newText = newText + words[x] + getSpaces(numberSpacesToAddEachWord);
            }
        }
        else 
            return text;
        return newText;
    }
    public static String getSpaces(int spaces){
        String text = "";
        for(int x = 0; x < spaces; x++){
            text+= " ";
        }
        return text;
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
Contrary    to    popular
belief,  Lorem  Ipsum  is
not simply random text.
It has roots in a piece
of    classical    Latin
literature  from  45  BC,
making it over 2000 years
old. Richard McClintock,
a  Latin  professor  at
Hampden-Sydney College in
Virginia, looked up one
of the more obscure Latin
words, consectetur, from
a  Lorem  Ipsum  passage,
and  going  through  the
cites  of  the  word  in
classical     literature,
discovered            the
undoubtable source. Lorem
Ipsum comes from sections
1.10.32  and  1.10.33  of
"de  Finibus  Bonorum  et
Malorum" (The Extremes of
Good and Evil) by Cicero,
written in 45 BC. This
book is a treatise on the
theory  of  ethics,  very
popular    during    the
Renaissance.  The  first
line  of  Lorem  Ipsum,
"Lorem  ipsum  dolor  sit
amet..",  comes  from  a
line in section 1.10.32.
```

It isn't perfect, since the spacing between the words is determined as the number of words in the line divided by how many extra spaces are needed to fill the gap, so the right line is not perfectly justified.  But it's more justified than before.

Answer (score 0):

That should not happen if your console uses a [monospaced font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font).